# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & due to &quot error

Tags: javascript, json

I am passing a JSON object to Javascript from Python which is a set of dates queried via SQLAlchemy from MySQL.

The set of dates has been formatted using

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(r,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

to look as follows:

```
["2008-01-31T00:00:00.000000", "2008-02-29T00:00:00.000000", "2008-03- 
 31T00:00:00.000000"]
```

but they come through as:

```
[&quot;2008-01-31T00:00:00.000000&quot;, &quot;2008-02-29T00:00:00.000000&quot;, &quot;2008-03-31T00:00:00.000000&quot;]
```

and I then get the syntax error.

I have tried:

```
var dates = ({{dates}}).replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"');
```

however this has no effect. I need to be able to pass this set of dates to a chart in ChartJS.

Comment: take a look to python on how it encode your text https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/encode

Answer (score -1):

Try it below ::

"&quot;2008-01-31T00:00:00.000000&quot;".replace(/&quot;/gi,'\"');

other wise data sending time service to replace respective format